# auto increase height on drag and drop element

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have code for drag and drop. but the problem is :
when I drag element from 1st div and drop it to 2nd div. then the height of 1st and 2nd div should be increase or decrease. depend upon size of elements.

Also the all divs (yellow) should have same height at all time.

to explain it I have image. and [Jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/metm0v0f/). 
[image]

in above image blue (mainPageDiv), pink (dashBoardContainer ) and yellow (dbContainer1 ,dbContainer2 and dbContainer3) are divs.

I hope I have explained enough.

**CSS**

```
   .mainPageDiv {
       min-height:100%, width:auto;
       margin:0 auto;
   }
   .dashBoardContainer {
       /*background lightcyan;*/
       width: 100%;
       overflow: hidden;
       padding: 15px 0px 10px 0px;
       position:absolute;
       border: dashed 2px red;
       overflow-y: scroll;
       background: #efefef;
   }
   .dbContainer1, .dbContainer2, .dbContainer3 {
       position:relative;
       margin: 10px;
       height: 100%;
       padding:10px;
   }
   .column {
       /* height: 100%; */
       margin:10px;
       width: 100%;
       border: solid green 2px;
   }
   .dbContainer1 {
       width: 40%;
       float: left;
       border: dotted 1px red;
   }
   .dbContainer2 {
       width: 40%;
       float: left;
       border: dotted 1px green;
   }
   .portlet:hover {
       /* cursor: pointer;
                    cursor: hand;*/
       -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
       -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
       box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
   }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="mainPageDiv">
    <div class="dashBoardContainer">
        <div class="dbContainer1 column">
            <div class="flip">
                <div class=" card">
                    <div class="face front">
                        <div class=" portlet   ">
                            <div class="portlet-header"> <span class="red text-uppercase"> Drag me </span>

                                <div class="dropdown pull-right "> <span class="pull-right ">
                                        <span class=""  id="edit-changes"><a href="#" > Edit <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil pull-right flipLink" > </span>

                                    </a>
                                    </span>
                                    </span>
                                    <hr class="hrflipForm">
                                </div>
                                <!-- portlet-content -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="portlet-content lastViewedArticle ">
                                <br>text
                                <br>text
                                <br>text
                                <br>text
                                <br>text
                                <br>text
                                <br>text
                                <br>text</div>
                            <!-- portlet-header -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- portlet- -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- moveOnchange-->
                    <div class="face back">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <div class="portlet">
                                <div class="flipForm">
                                    <ul class="list-inline pull-right ">
                                        <li class="flipControl" id="save-changes"> <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk gi-1x opacity7 "></span>

                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <hr class="hrflipForm">
                                </div>
                                <!-- Header Closed -->
                                <div class="portlet-content lastViewedArticle ">
                                    <br>text
                                    <br>text
                                    <br>text
                                    <br>text
                                    <br>text
                                    <br>text
                                    <br>text
                                    <br>text
                                    <br>text
                                    <br>text
                                    <br>text
                                    <br>text</div>
                                <!--- Portlet content -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- dbContainer1 -->
        </div>
        <div class="dbContainer2 column">
            <div class="flip">
                <div class=" card">
                    <div class="face front">
                        <div class=" portlet   ">
                            <div class="portlet-header"> <span class="red text-uppercase">  Drag me </span>

                                <div class="dropdown pull-right "> <span class="pull-right ">
                                        <span class=""  id="edit-changes"><a href="#" > Edit <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil pull-right flipLink" > </span>

                                    </a>
                                    </span>
                                    </span>
                                    <hr class="hrflipForm">
                                </div>
                                <!-- portlet-content -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="portlet-content lastViewedArticle ">
                                <br>text
                                <br>text
                                <br>text
                                <br>text
                                <br>text
                                <br>text
                                <br>text
                                <br>text</div>
                            <!-- portlet-header -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- portlet- -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- moveOnchange-->
                    <div class="face back">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <div class="portlet">
                                <div class="flipForm">
                                    <ul class="list-inline pull-right ">
                                        <li class="flipControl" id="save-changes"> <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk gi-1x opacity7 "></span>

                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <hr class="hrflipForm">
                                </div>
                                <!-- Header Closed -->
                                <div class="portlet-content lastViewedArticle ">
                                    <br>text
                                    <br>text
                                    <br>text
                                    <br>text
                                    <br>text
                                    <br>text
                                    <br>text
                                    <br>text
                                    <br>text
                                    <br>text
                                    <br>text
                                    <br>text</div>
                                <!--- Portlet content -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- dbContainer2 -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Jquery/JS **

```
$(function () {
    $(".column").sortable({
        connectWith: ".column",
        handle: ".portlet-header",
        cancel: ".portlet-toggle",
        placeholder: "portlet-placeholder ui-corner-all"
    });


    $(".portlet")
        .addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all")
        .find(".portlet-header")
        .addClass("ui-widget-header ui-corner-all")
    $(".portlet-toggle").click(function () {
        var icon = $(this);
        icon.toggleClass("ui-icon-minusthick ui-icon-plusthick");
        icon.closest(".portlet").find(".portlet-content").toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Your fiddle works fine.. I didn't find issue in auto resizing..

Comment: Sorry @GuruprasadRao, it was incomplete question. please have look now.

Comment: Can you replicate the problem shown in image into fiddle?

Comment: did you find any solution to this problem ?